# unable to mount sd card

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have a pre - installed windows 8 PC which I have partitioned with Ubuntu 12.10 . 
I am able to mount the SD card in windows 8, but when I put it in when running Ubuntu , nothing happens . it doesn't appear in the media folder either. Here is `lsusb`:

```
enter codeBus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1d57:32da Xenta 2.4GHz Receiver (Keyboard and Mouse)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5165 IMC Networks 


lscpi
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)



dmesg | tail :

[   22.986262] cfg80211: Found new beacon on frequency: 2472 MHz (Ch 13) on phy0
[   23.236412] init: anacron main process (1078) killed by TERM signal
[   23.486446] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1258) terminated with status 1
[   27.222396] wlan0: authenticate with e0:69:95:b6:01:42
[   27.237975] wlan0: send auth to e0:69:95:b6:01:42 (try 1/3)
[   27.239515] wlan0: authenticated
[   27.250064] wlan0: associate with e0:69:95:b6:01:42 (try 1/3)
[   27.253585] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:69:95:b6:01:42 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   27.253923] wlan0: associated
[   27.254274] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Someone please help , as I really need to be able to use my SD card .

Thanks !!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Do you have any indications that your SD card reader is recognized and working properly in Ubuntu? Please provide the output of `lsusb` and `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(card|mmc|sd)"` run from a terminal? And please also provide the output of `dmesg | tail` right after you put in the SD card. Provide this info by **editing** your question.

Comment: what is the code for providing the "lsusb"

Comment: You open a command line,type `lsusb` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Your card reader is not supported out of the box it seems: [LP Bug #971876: Realtek Card Reader RTL8411 Device 5289 (PCI 03:00.0) Driver and udisks Rule](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876) (workaround in the meantime is posted there in [comment #17](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876/comments/17))

Comment: I tried that and  sudo pluma command  was not found

Comment: @shreesh Just use another editor that *is* available, e.g. `gksudo gedit ....` instead of `sudo pluma ...`.

Comment: the line DRIVERS=="rts_bpp", ENV{ID_DRIVE_FLASH_SD}="1" is already there